# Manually Login by Facebook in Angular6 and Laravel

Tags: javascript, facebook, angular6, facebook-login

I'm developing an application which I'm writing in Angular 6 framework.

Currently, I would like to add user login by social media like: Facebook, Google, Twitter, Github, LinkedIn.

I have a four buttons for these actions in my **SocialLoginComponent's** template: 
[image]

Now I'm trying to implement user login by facebook after clicking on **CONNECT WITH FACEBOOK** button which has an click angular action:

```
<button (click) = "loginWithFacebook()" class="social-button" id="facebook-connect"> <span>Connect with Facebook</span></button>
```

Implementation of function loginWithFacebook looks like:

```
  loginWithFacebook() {
            this.auth.loginByFacebook(this.apiKey, this.redirectUri).subscribe({
                next: (v) => console.log(v)
            });
        }
```

Here auth is of course service injected by constructor:

```
 constructor(private auth: AuthService) {
    }
```

Below I show implementation method loginByFacebook method in my AuthService:

```
loginByFacebook(appId, redirectUri) {
         const facebookParams = new HttpParams()
            .set('client_id', appId)
            .set('redirect_uri', redirectUri)
            .set('response_type', 'token');
        return this.http.get(this.facebookUrl, {params : facebookParams});
        });
```

where facebookUrl is the AuthService property:

```
private facebookUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/v3.1/dialog/oauth';
```

I'm setting up here of course parameters based on My Facebook App.

I'm trying to invoke that url by get method in order to obtain a facebook login dialog based on description from tutorial: [manualyBuildALoginFlow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/). I wouldn't like to use JavaScript SDK in my solution.

In current state when I'm clicking on the faecebook button, there is response  like below:

[image]
[image]

I would like to obtain modal dialog with confirmation like below:

[image]

In my Get request I add parameter **response_type = token** in order to obtain Social token. On the below diagram I show what flow I'm trying to achieve: 
[image]
On above diagram my server is laravel framework which currently handle user login and returns JWT token in order to check that user's  logged in to application. Next this token I save in local storage by Angular6 framework.

How could I obtain that redirection with modal window in Angular6? What I'm doing wrong is that redirection dosen't work? What first step should I do in order to implement such authorization using facebook?

I would be greateful for advices. 
Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to invoke that url by get method

Which means an AJAX request … and that is of course not possible.

You need to *redirect* the user to the login dialog URL, not try and request it in the background - for the simple reason, that users need to be able to verify via the browser address bar, that they are indeed entering their login credentials to Facebook, and not some phishing site. If you requested it via AJAX and displayed it “within” your page, that would not be possible.

Comment: Ok, I've understood. Maybe I could do something like that: this.router.navigate('https://www.facebook.com/v3.1/dialog/oauth?myParams')?

Comment: As long as that causes the URL to be opened in the top window instance … Otherwise, there’s always the plain old, pure-JS `window.location.href = "..."`

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented method as **misorude** suggests in my Auth Service:

```
  loginWithFacebook(appId: number, redirectUri: string) {
        window.location.href =  `https://www.facebook.com/v3.1/dialog/oauth?client_id=${appId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=token&display=popup`;
    }
```

Currently the page redirects to my Facebook app. Next I confirm my login by Facebook in dialog window. Then browser redirect back to my Angular app and in my url I have Social token from Facebook like on the picture below:

[image]

Next I'd like to obtain this token from url and then to implement the data flow as below:

[image]

How should I correctly get an access token and post to my backend Server as on the schema above?

I would be greateful for help

Best regards